# How to force ssh-add to ask passphrase when loading RSA key from FIFO?

Tags: shell, pipe, io, ssh-agent, fifo

I've created the following RSA key (with passphrase):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f rsa_foo
```

Now when adding the key in normal way, `ssh-add` asks for the passphrase fine:

```
$ ssh-add rsa_foo
Enter passphrase for rsa_foo: 12345
```

However when I'm loading the key through FIFO, it doesn't ask anymore:

```
$ mkfifo -m=600 fifo
$ cat rsa_foo >fifo | ssh-add fifo
```

and it gives me the following error instead:

- OS X:

  > ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
- Linux (Ubuntu):

  > ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

This works when RSA key file doesn't have passphrase.

How do I fix the above error in order so `ssh-add` can ask the passphrase normally (or I could pass to it somehow)?

My goal is to load this RSA key using FIFO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does ask me for the password:

```
$ ls -l fifo
prw------- 1 glopes users 0 Out 11 03:59 fifo
$ ssh-add fifo
Enter passphrase for fifo:
```

Then load the key from another terminal:

```
$ cat id_rsa > fifo
```

Or try the following one-liner:

```
$ (cat id_rsa > fifo &); ssh-add fifo
```

Right on the terminal, without calling `$SSH_ASKPASS`, like the manual says:

> If ssh-add needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from the current terminal if it was run from a terminal.  If  ssh-add  does not have a terminal associated with it but `DISPLAY` and `SSH_ASKPASS` are set, it will execute the program specified by `SSH_ASKPASS` (by default ``ssh-askpass)'' and open an X11 window to read the passphrase.

You can always work around it by decrypting the key explicitly before passing it to ssh-add.

Comment: @kenorb Just `cat id_rsa > fifo` from another terminal.